# Can we use Bind attribute with Get action method while passing parameter in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fortify

I'm having 2 more errors with HPFortify along with main question as following for below given code:
1. ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Without AntiForgery Validation [Note: due to Bind attribute, it might be asking for this error. So, I put ValidateAntiForgeryToken in code. But, it again asked to change the verb to POST]
2. ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST
Is it correct or need to be changed something?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]   
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
public Actionresult Index([Bind(Include="Eid, Eage")]EmpModel objEmpModel)    
{   
return view(objEmpModel);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `[HttpPost]` to work with a complex object like this:

```
[HttpPost]   
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
public Actionresult Index(EmpModel objEmpModel)    
{   
return view(objEmpModel);    
}
```

Or if you want your code to work, use this:

```
[HttpGet]   
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
public Actionresult Index([FromUri]EmpModel objEmpModel)    
{   
return view(objEmpModel);    
}
```

**Note:** For complex types like classes, web-api tries to read the data from body, since you are using `[HttpGet]` method, so `[FromUri]` attribute overrides the default convention and reads the data from Uri instead of body. More Info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Bind includes around 20-25 parameters. HPFortify declares it requires antiforgerytoken though method defined as GET clearly. Method supposed to be POST for using ValidateAntiForgeryToken. So, not getting whats wrong there?

Comment: `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] ` if you change it to `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] `, then what happens?

Comment: Happens nothing. As, it takes parameter into model through Bind and returning view simply without any db or service call. Surprising call is that when I wrote ValidateAntiForgeryToken, the 1st error got resolved. Is it Ok? if change it to POST? or put second error as false positive?